# Android best use AsyncTask, Service or other

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I'm a student writing some app to understand and study Android Development.
I'm trying to write an app the should work like this:

### MapActivity:

Show a map with user position and open Access point in a range.
User and AP position should be received by the "MainClass".

### MainClass:

This should do the main work. It should get user position, get open access point from db and insert into the db new open AP found with WifiManager scans.

Now, the MainClass should work in background, on user agree, even if the app is closed.

My questions are:

1. Should I do MainClass stuff on a new thread or on the UI thread?
2. Should MainClass be an AsyncTask, Service or other? please tell me why too.
3. the scan operation return a scan that get executed in a registered receiver. Does it run on UI thread or in a new one?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE;

So, if i'm not messing what are you saying, the service should look like this:

```
public class MainService extends Service {
    Thread mainThread;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ....
                mainOperation();
                ....
            }
        });
        mainThread.setPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mainThread.run();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

does START_STICKY on kill call onStartCommand or onCreate?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Should I do MainClass stuff on a new thread or on the UI thread?

**Answer:**
You should do on the background thread (new thread) because android does not allow network tasks on UI thread also if you do time taking operation on UI thread UI will freeze

> 2. Should MainClass be an AsyncTask, Service or other? please tell me why too.

**Answer:** 
As you clearly said your requirement **(MainClass should work in background)** you need to use [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) because service runs in background even when your app is killed

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use MainClass.java stuff into a background thread. i.e., Service
2. Service will trigger data through Broadcast receiver.
3. Broadcast receiver will send data to MapActivity.java. Registered receiver's onReceive() method always run in the UI thread.

If you want to run MainClass.java stuff in foreground you can use MVP pattern. You should do your stuff into presentation layer.

Comment: Good answer, but more specific: I think he needs a foreground service. As it has to run even when the app is closed. With Android doze mode, there is no other option to accomplish this (as I know of).

Comment: @jobbert, There is an option to accomplish this case using MVP pattern.

Comment: @jobbert you are correct.  If OP does not want the service to be killed at the OS's whim then a foreground service is what they need.

Comment: Ok so, should i use Service or IntentService? if I' m right: Service run on the UI thread but with startForeground() in goes on a new one? IntentService have own thread so its mostly like the one i need? Do they get killed by os, and if yes how to restart?

Comment: OP, you need a normal service that you start in the Foreground. Otherwise Android will kill the resources in the background to prevent battery loss. An intent service is used when you intent to get something big in the background and not what you need right now. With this information, you should be able to search everything on Google/SO to make it work. @Silambarasan Poonguti, I was not talking about how to get the information from the service.

Answer (score 0):

Background Service will be the best and only solution for your requirements I guess. Because you want your operation to keep running even when your app is closed.